# How can I write a rigorous function for this case in C++

Tags: c++, parsing

The function is simple just take a string with format (1,2) to get 1,2 as two integers from it.

But how to write it rigorous? say could detech invalid input. But I do not want to read character by character, is there any default function for this?

Comment: how long is a piece of string? give some code example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way I know is to copy-paste these in a header, which let you "stream in" literals in an intuitive manner:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <cstring>

template<class e, class t, int N>
std::basic_istream<e,t>& operator>>(std::basic_istream<e,t>& in, const e(&stringlit)[N]) {
        std::array<e, N-1> buffer; //get buffer
        in >> buffer[0]; //skips whitespace
        if (N>2)
                in.read(&buffer[1], N-2); //read the rest
        if (strncmp(&buffer[0], stringlit, N-1)) //if it failed
                in.setstate(in.rdstate() | std::ios::failbit); //set the state
        return in;
}
template<class e, class t>
std::basic_istream<e,t>& operator>>(std::basic_istream<e,t>& in, const e& charlit) {
        e buffer;  //get buffer
        in >> buffer; //read data
        if (buffer != charlit) //if it failed
                in.setstate(in.rdstate() | std::ios::failbit); //set the state
        return in;
}
//redirect mutable char arrays to their normal function
template<class e, class t, int N>
std::basic_istream<e,t>& operator>>(std::basic_istream<e,t>& in, e(&carray)[N]) {
        return std::operator>>(in, carray);
}
```

Then your code is simply this:

```
if (stream >> '(' >> leftnum >> ',' >> rightnum >> ')' )
    ; //success
else
    ; //invalid input
```

A far more common way is regexes:

```
std::string line;
std::getline(stream, line);
std::regex re("\(([0-9]+),([0-9]+)\)");
std::smatch match;
if (std::regex_match(stream, match, re) && match.size() > 1)
    ; //success
else
    ; //invalid input
```

Comment: Simplest, maybe not, but definitely nice functions.

Comment: @Quentin: How is `if (stream >> '(' >> leftnum >> ',' >> rightnum >> ')' )` not simple?  You mean the functions are complex? He doesn't have to write the functions, I already did.

Comment: Yes, I was talking about the functions, but I just found it funny : "The simplest way I know is * **dumps load of code** * and voilà !" :D

Comment: @Quentin: reworded to make it clearer that the user doesn't need to bother to understand or even read the functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main() {
    int a, b;
    if(std::scanf("(%d,%d)", &a, &b) != 2) {
        // Error ! Recover or give up.
    }

    // a and b contain your values.

    return 0;
}
```

This is of course extensible to whatever your format is, but `std::scanf` is what you need.

Comment: It will automatically exclude '(' and ','?

Comment: @大王花 yes. `std::scanf` does basic pattern-matching, parsing `%`'s into variables. More on it [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf).

Comment: I was trying to think of normal ways, I can't believe I forgot `scanf`.